# I am not getting any sound out of my PA system. Did I connect something incorrectly?

Tags: mixer, amplifier, setup, power

I have a NUMARK M6 USB 4 channel mixer with LEFT and RIGHT  Balanced XLR output connected to channel 1 and channel 2 of my AUDAC EPA252 power amplifier respectively. My speaker is a passive HYBRID PB15L @400W(800W peak) connected via Speakon to my EPA252 in bridged mode. My problem is that no sound is coming out of the speaker, and the amplifier goes into standby mode after about 30seconds(according to the amplifier site,this is due to no signal received). I've read multiple articles and blogs, and watched multiple videos but still cant find any help regarding this issue. Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: If you send two channels to the power amp, don´t set it up in bridge mode. Check the manual,

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking the row of LED-s on the Numark. They show the output level from the Numark. If they are not blinking, the Numark does not send any signal. If not, where is your signal supposed to come from? You need to check the settings in the Numark or the input source.

Turn up the levels on the Numark so that at least half of the red LED-s light up.

Start by turning up the "volume" of the amplifier. Check the green light "Signal" on the amplifier. If it does not light up you have a problem in between the output of the Numark and the input of the amplifier.

It might be the cable, check with different XLR cables. If the cables are OK, it might be a problem with the Numark outputs. See if you can connect the mixer to something else that shows if there is a signal.

Basic technique in finding errors is to divide the problem, take on piece at a time. Follow the signal flow and see where it stops behaving as expected.